# How to set the global environment variable from jenkins pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, aws-sts

I would like to ask if there would be a shortcut way to set the global environment variables generated by `aws sts assume-role` on one jenkins pipeline. My aim is to have these generated values `(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SESSION_TOKEN)` reusable to the 3 stage steps on one jenkins pipeline. Currently I have this setup on my stages though I find it too messy and I would like to know if youy can suggest me a better way to set the global variables. My current Pipeline looks like this:

> ```
>    pipeline {
>    agent any
>    stages {
>           stage ('S3 CHECK') {
>               steps {
>                  sh '''
>                  unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
>                  unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
>                  unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
> ```

```
                CREDENTIALS=`aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::0123456789123:role/POGI --role-session-name RoleSession`

                export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=`echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId'`
                export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=`echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey'`
                export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=`echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken'`
                aws s3 ls
                '''
              }
           }
           stage ('CHECK AVAILABLE BEANSTALK PLATFORMS') {
              steps {
                 sh '''
                 unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
                 unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                 unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

                        CREDENTIALS=`aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::0123456789123:role/POGI --role-session-name RoleSession`

                export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=`echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId'`
                export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=`echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey'`
                export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=`echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken'`
                aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environment-resources --environment-name pogi
                aws elasticbeanstalk list-platform-versions 
                '''
              }
           }
           stage ('BEANSTALK CHECK') {
              steps {
                 sh '''
                 unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
                 unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                 unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

                        CREDENTIALS=`aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::0123456789123:role/POGI --role-session-name RoleSession`

                export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=`echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId'`
                export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=`echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey'`
                export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=`echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken'`
                aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environment-resources --environment-name pogi
                '''
              }
           }
    }
```

}

I really want to elimate on placing this per stage to make the format more clean

```
                 unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
                 unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                 unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

                        CREDENTIALS=`aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::0123456789123:role/POGI --role-session-name RoleSession`

                export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=`echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId'`
                export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=`echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey'`
                export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=`echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken'`
                aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environment-resources --environment-name pogi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract out this into a bash file and then use `source <bash-file>.sh` in each stage.

For example you can call the file `init.sh` and have the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

CREDENTIALS=`aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::0123456789123:role/POGI --role-session-name RoleSession`

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=`echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId'`
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=`echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey'`
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=`echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken'`
```

For example, this way the `CHECK AVAILABLE BEANSTALK PLATFORMS` stage would become the following:

```sh
source init.sh

aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environment-resources --environment-name pogi
aws elasticbeanstalk list-platform-versions
```

And if different stages has some variables, you can use something like `source init.sh var1 var2` and `var1` would be `$1` in `init.sh` and `var2` would be `$2`.

As an aside, you can get rid of the `jq` dep and just use `awk` instead. This is for MFA (but the same approach can be used for assume-role) using AWS `text` format instead of JSON.

```sh
# output format "CREDENTIALS <spaces> <access-key-id> <expiry> <secret-access-key> <session-token>"
CREDENTIALS=`aws sts get-session-token --output text \
  --serial-number <mfa-arn> \
  --token-code <otp> \
  --duration-seconds 43200`

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo $CREDENTIALS | awk '{print $2}')
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo $CREDENTIALS | awk '{print $4}')
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo $CREDENTIALS | awk '{print $5}')
```